# The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception. After downgrading to entity framework 5 from 6

Tags: entity-framework, app-config, odp.net

I'm trying to get Entity Framework working with and Oracle database.

I originally had entity framework 6 installed but now I've downgraded to EF 5 because I've read EF6 doesn't work with ODP.NET.

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
```

This is my app config, config section. I've reinstalled EF 5 on all my projects but keep getting this error.

Comment: Try removing `, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`, probably the assembly full name doesn't match with the reference

Comment: same thing happened to me.. i ended up deleting the project and creating new one.

Comment: My case is related to this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859153/entity-framework-unrecognized-element-providers-exception