# Crud Operations in Entity Framework Codefirst in MVC 4 Using MySql Database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

To do CRUD operation I am adding controller and datacontext in scaffolding Options i have received this error

> unable to retrieve metadata unable to cast object of type
>   system.data.entity.core.objects.objectcontext to

This is my Model

```
namespace MvcMySql.Models
{
public class Code
{
 [Key]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext()
        : base("ConnectionString")
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Code>().HasKey(p => p.StudentID);
    }
    public DbSet<Code> CodeFirsts { get; set; }
 }
}
```

My web Config

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionString"connectionString="server=10.10.30.164;uid=demouser;password=welcome;database=demo"
providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

 <system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
 <providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF5, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
</providers>
```

I cant identify where the error occurs[image: this message i got while doing crud operations]

Comment: Did you build the solution after adding model?

Comment: yes I build the solution after add model

Comment: EF6 has some issues with mvc 4. Either use mvc5 or use EF5.
Follow this tutorial.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: I have used version 5 only

Comment: I am able to reproduce your issue with EF5. Restarted VS and build sln but problem persist.

Comment: If you have <providers> section in web.config, remove it. I will add details as answer.

Comment: MySQL is try to use EF5 instead of EF6. Try to change the type provider to something like <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></provider>

Comment: your provider is EF6 it will not work sir

Comment: @DhasarathanT - Did you tried removing the provider as I suggested in my answer below? Does it work?

Comment: yes sir i removed but the error occurs

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices is EF5.  System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices is EF6. You are mixing EF versions. In MS SqlServer you are trying to use EF6 and in MySql you are trying to use EF5.

Comment: @Dhasarathan T you are right. You are not mixing EF version in web.config. But it seems that VS do. Check the error popup namespaces.

Comment: ya what there mistake ji

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this issue locally. Then in order to solve it I searched "unrecognized element 'providers' entity framework" on Google as it was the error given on the message box.

The first [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859153/entity-framework-unrecognized-element-providers-exception) suggested me to remove parameter section but it was not present in my web.config file.

I reviewed my web.config files from other projects and found that It does not have a `<providers>` section in `<entityFramework>`.

In my current web.config I found it is there (due to downgrade to EF5 from EF6). Providers are introduced from EF6, read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx#Providers).

Current web.config has:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

I removed the provider section and build the solution. Then tried adding the controller using scaffolding and bingo... it worked this time... Now my web.config looks like below:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: sir it asking provider now

Comment: @DhasarathanT - EF5 does not use provider. Something got mismatched in your configuration (may be due to downgrading to EF v5). Did you removed both the provider or just one for "System.Data.SqlClient"?

Comment: sir i have removed both the provider and added entity framework what you have given sir

Comment: Nah, try keeping what you have got in original and just remove one provider for "System.Data.SqlClient".