# Server error in Web Config of VS ASP.NET MVC Solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, web-config

I recently inherited am ASP.NET MVC website to hots on my server from a different team within the organization.  The solution was built in VS 2012 and I am testing it in VS 2013 before I start hosting on the serer. There were a number of assembly dependency issues that I have fixed - I updated MVC in Nuget and also had to install and earlier version of EF (4.0.0.0) to get the solution to compile.

Now I am faced with another issue in the Web.Config file.  The following screenshot presents the issue I am having:

[image]

There are only 3 scenarios that I can think of that is causing this which are the following:

- 1) Something happened when I updated MVC
- 2) Something happened when    installed EF 4.0.0.0
- 3) The connection string to the old server is    still in Web.Config
  (the only reason I don't think this is the issue    is because the
  database it is calling is still in existance and the    data is still
  there)

I was hoping somebody with more experience with MVC and/or EF could help me troubleshoot this.

Comment: according to this SO you should try just deleting that section http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859153/entity-framework-unrecognized-element-providers-exception

Comment: @JamieD77  Wow....That worked...I was going to do this but didn't think that was going to solve anything...always just give it a go I guess.  If you add an answer I'll accept it...or do you think I should just delete question?